# Predicate in wait only called once when using notify in loop

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

When calling the `notify_once` method on a condition variable within a loop in one thread, it appears that the `wait` method in another thread only checks it predicate once. Example code is listed below:

```
int someNumber = 0;
mutex numberMutex;
condition_variable cv;

void waitFunction()
{
  unique_lock<mutex> lock(numberMutex);
  auto duration = chrono::seconds(5);

  // Predicate is only called once?
  cv.wait_for(lock, duration, []() {
    cout << "Checking condition: 10 == " << someNumber << '\n';
    return someNumber == 10;
  });
  cout << "Done with this thread...\n" << flush;
}

int main()
{
  thread waiter(waitFunction);

  for (size_t number = 0; number != 50; ++number)
  {
    {
      lock_guard<mutex> guard(numberMutex);
      someNumber = number;
    }
    cv.notify_one();
  }

  waiter.join();
}
```

Executing this program gives the following output

```
Checking condition: 10 == 49
Checking condition: 10 == 49
Done with this thread...
```

while I would expect it to check the condition at each iteration.

How is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The signaling thread doesn't *wait* for the signal to have been received.

This means that the waiting thread might not get a chance to wake up before the main loop repeated and incremented again.

You have an "ordinary" race condition (though not a language level data race, so no UB).

Here's a counter example. Depending on the speed and scheduling fancies of your platform, the following:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/250b78addb1834d7)</kbd>**

```
#include <condition_variable>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

using namespace std;

int someNumber = 0;
mutex numberMutex;
condition_variable cv;

void waitFunction() {
    unique_lock<mutex> lock(numberMutex);
    auto duration = chrono::seconds(5);

    // Predicate is only called once?
    cv.wait_for(lock, duration, []() {
        cout << "Checking condition: 10 == " << someNumber << '\n';
        return someNumber == 10;
    });
    cout << "Done with this thread...\n" << flush;
}

int main() {
    thread waiter(waitFunction);

    for (size_t number = 0; number != 50; ++number) {
        this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(1));
        {
            lock_guard<mutex> guard(numberMutex);
            someNumber = number;
            std::cout << "notif: " << number  << "\n";
            cv.notify_one();
        }
    }

    waiter.join();
}
```

Might prints something like:

```
Checking condition: 10 == 0
notif: 0
Checking condition: 10 == 0
notif: 1
Checking condition: 10 == 1
notif: 2
Checking condition: 10 == 2
notif: 3
Checking condition: 10 == 3
notif: 4
Checking condition: 10 == 4
notif: 5
Checking condition: 10 == 5
notif: 6
Checking condition: 10 == 6
notif: 7
Checking condition: 10 == 7
notif: 8
Checking condition: 10 == 8
notif: 9
Checking condition: 10 == 9
notif: 10
Checking condition: 10 == 10
Done with this thread...
notif: 11
notif: 12
notif: 13
notif: 14
notif: 15
notif: 16
notif: 17
notif: 18
notif: 19
notif: 20
notif: 21
notif: 22
notif: 23
notif: 24
notif: 25
notif: 26
notif: 27
notif: 28
notif: 29
notif: 30
notif: 31
notif: 32
notif: 33
notif: 34
notif: 35
notif: 36
notif: 37
notif: 38
notif: 39
notif: 40
notif: 41
notif: 42
notif: 43
notif: 44
notif: 45
notif: 46
notif: 47
notif: 48
notif: 49
```

### RATIONALE

If you need two-way communication, set a flag to signal the main thread back (e.g. use a different condition variable)

Comment: As a side note consider signaling the cv under the mutex for improved scheduling guarantees